# Raspberry pi 3 SSH Access Denied Using Putty from Windows

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

So i Setup my Raspberry and Tried to SSH into the Pi. When i connect to the Host using x ip address on Putty i get the terminal to input my User, Lets call it "MyPi" and when prompted to enter the password i get an access Denied issue.

"Yes im new to this"

Im using the latest version of Raspbian loaded on the pi. I got 2 screens, 1 for my main pc trying to ssh into the pie and 1 screen for the pi, both keyboard and mouses are plugged into both pcs so can individually control them. My Pi is connected via wifi to my router, and my pc is also wirelessly connected to the router

Things i tried :

- Logging in as The User and password setup in the Preferences >>> Raspberry Pi configuration on the Pi >> "MyPi" with the password i set
- Logging in as the pi user with raspberry password
- Logging in as root.
- Tried Resetting the root password using >> sudo su passwd or sudo su passwd
- Loaded an entirely new image to start from scratch and retied the above.

Am I missing something i needed installed? I enabled SSH the SSH server on the Pi on the configuration / Interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently on Raspbian SSH is switch off.
You have several ways to activate ssh.

With monitor and keyboard use at Prompt `sudo raspi-config`.
And go to Menu 7 -> Menu A4 and enable SSH.

Headless, use another computer and create a file named `ssh` at the boot partition so next time you boot the Raspberry SSH is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use systemctl to start the service

`sudo systemctl enable ssh
 sudo systemctl start ssh`

If your Pi is connected to the internet, you should change its default password to ensure that it remains secure.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that on my raspberry with NOOBS OS was user pi without password. Problem was solved by changing password on pi user. Then I can ssh from win 10 with PUTTY.
My advice is not to login as root but instead change password on pi user and log in as pi user.

Answer (score 0):

One of my problems was having the wrong keyboard layout when setting your password, resulting in different characters in the password you thought you typed in. Worth checking out! You can check [this link](https://raspberrytips.com/keyboard-layout-on-raspberry-pi/) to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

A simple plug out and plug in the power cable of pi worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I have the pi 4. Out of the box for putty username and password are both root.